# MYSQL using WHERE IN along with AND for several criteria SELECT clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I want to select from a SQL table all rows where the ID matches the ID of another table but where TIMESTAMP corresponding to the ID in the first table is less than the TIMESTAMP corresponding to the ID in the second table.

So far, I have:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id 
FROM table2 t2)
AND (t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp);
```

My question is, will this AND condition know to make sure both criteria are fulfilled simultaneously on the same rows? That is, will it test the inequality of the TIMESTAMP of the ID in question? Or will it check if the ID is in the other table and then test inequality between the TIMESTAMP of the first row in each table independently (not necessarily matching up)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.id
WHERE table1.timestamp < table2.timestamp
```

And it's a best practice never use SELECT *.

Comment: Is this going to return everything from both tables? or just table1?

Comment: I think from both tables. I repeat, This is a bad practice! You should only return the columns you need...

Comment: so if I specify table1.* it should only return table1 data?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my common sense says that is... just test it!